# How can I modify this trigger to include column-name, old-value and new-value?

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, triggers

Suppose, a trigger that keeps track of `AREA`-table and records the changes in `AREA_LOGGING_TABLE`.

```
 CREATE TABLE AREA
   (    AREA_NUMBER NUMBER, 
    AREA_NAME VARCHAR(20)
   )

CREATE TABLE AREA_LOGGING_TABLE 
   (    WHO_MODIFIED VARCHAR(20), 
    WHEN_MODIFIED DATE, 
    OLD_VALUE BLOB, 
    NEW_VALUE BLOB, 
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(30)
   )
```

I want to record username, date-time, column-name, old-data, and, new-data.

How can I do that?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AREA_MODIFY_LOGGER_COLUMN_LVL 
        AFTER INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE
            ON AREA 
            REFERENCING OLD AS old_data NEW AS new_data 
            FOR EACH ROW  
        DECLARE
            v_username varchar2(10);

        BEGIN

           -- Find username of person performing the DELETE on the table
           SELECT user INTO v_username
           FROM dual;

           -- Insert record into audit table
           INSERT INTO AREA_LOGGING_TABLE(who_modified, when_modified, old_value, new_value)
           VALUES ( v_username, sysdate, :old_data.area_number, :new_data.area_number);

       END;
```

This is not working.

Besides, I don't know how to include column-name here.

Comment: Are you getting any error that you can post here?

Comment: Error(25,43): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BLOB got NUMBER
Error(24,12): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Ok.. I think you also need to post table structures for AREA and AREA_LOGGING_TABLE, it seems the data types being inserted do not match those in the AREA_LOGGING_TABLE.    Also check this [article](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2455027?start=0&tstart=0) which provides some guidance on detecting column changes..

Comment: Why are `old_value` and `new_value` declared as `BLOB`?  Why isn't your `INSERT` statement including the `column_name` column?

Comment: @JustinCave, coz, I don't know how to obtain column-name.

Comment: @JustinCave, coz, old_valu and new-value should be able to accept any type of data.

Comment: Why would you want to accept "any type of data" if the table you're tracking changes on only has a `number` and a `varchar2(20)` column?  That's going to add a lot of complexity to your code particularly when you try to read the data back and convert it to something meaningful.  If you're storing character data in a `blob`, for example, you'll have to specify what character set you want to use for converting the string into a binary representation (and do the same when reading it back). And that gets harder the more literally you want to take "any type of data"-- what about user-defined types?

Comment: Reat this thread, it may be helpfull in your case: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055

Answer (score 0):

The `utl_raw.cast_to_raw` function can be used to convert your values to `BLOB`. 
Regarding the column_name, I think you can hard code it in the insert statement as you already doing it after `:NEW` and `:OLD`.

The `nvl` function was used to handle nulls in `:NEW` \ `:OLD`.

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AREA_MODIFY_LOGGER_COLUMN_LVL 
            AFTER INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE
                ON AREA 
                REFERENCING OLD AS Old NEW AS New
                FOR EACH ROW  
            DECLARE
                v_username varchar2(10);

            BEGIN

               -- Find username of person performing the DELETE on the table
               SELECT user INTO v_username
               FROM dual;


                if nvl(:old.area_number, -1) <> nvl(:new.area_number, -1) then
                   -- Insert record into audit table
                   INSERT INTO AREA_LOGGING_TABLE(who_modified, when_modified, old_value, new_value, column_name)
                   VALUES ( v_username, sysdate, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:Old.area_number), utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:New.area_number), 'AREA_NUMBER');
                end if;

               if nvl(:old.area_name , '-1')  <> nvl(:new.area_name, '-1')   then
               -- Insert record into audit table
                INSERT INTO AREA_LOGGING_TABLE(who_modified, when_modified, old_value, new_value, column_name)
                VALUES ( v_username, sysdate, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:Old.AREA_NAME), utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:New.AREA_NAME), 'AREA_NAME');
              end if;

       END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to giving you brief for trigger to enhance your concept for trigger
You have below inbuilt table created by SQL when trigger fired.
-  deleted (i.e. select @empid=d.Emp_ID from deleted d)
-  inserted (i.e. select @empid=i.Emp_ID from inserted i) (can be used in Insert/update operation)